# WebStorm shortcut for object inspector popup

Tags: node.js, debugging, keyboard-shortcuts, webstorm

While debugging in WebStorm if you hover over an object you get this tooltip:

[image]

If you click on the tooltip or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> you get an object inspector pop up:

[image]

Is there a shortcut for getting this popup?

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> only works after you hover over the object and the tooltip appears. I'd like to be navigate the cursor to an object and then use a shortcut to get the popup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd> (Quick evaluate expression)